# Cocoapods 1.1.1 target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1

I have updated to cocoapods 1.1.1 for my XCode 8 Swift 2.0 project and now I'm getting the warning "...target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` ..." in the console. How can I fix this?

Here my podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def app_pods
 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0.0'
 pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper','~> 4.0.0'
 pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 2.0.2'
 pod 'KeychainAccess', '~> 3.0.0'
 pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
 pod 'SwiftyBeaver', '~> 1.0.1'
 pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.17.0'
end

def unit_tests
 app_pods
 pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 5.2.1'
 pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift', '~> 5.2.1'
end 


target 'Demo' do
 app_pods
end

target 'App1' do
 app_pods
end

target 'App2' do
 app_pods
end

target 'DemoTests' do
 unit_tests
end

target 'App1Tests' do
 unit_tests
end

target 'App2Tests' do
 unit_tests
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by doing the following:

1. Go into Build Settings
2. At the top select **All** and **Combined**
3. Under Build Options you should see **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** and it is bold.
4. Click on it and click delete. It should now be unbolded.
5. Pod install and the error/errors should go away!

It wont let me post an image because i don't have enough reputation, so here is a detailed screen shot link!

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/17066507/21532583/93df897e-cd1f-11e6-9f17-d25cb81a2a53.png

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works, but now you have to make sure all of your teammates are performing it each `pod install`.

And we all know they won't.

You could make CococaPods do it automatically, by adding this to the bottom of your `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.name == 'MyPOD' 
                config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'Yes'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

More info here: https://www.devsbedevin.net/cocoapods-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the following pull request https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6068 and it should be out in cocoapods version 1.1.2 . I got the info from the following github issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6067